# How to kill threads spawned when using the multiprocessing's Pool imap_unordered

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to speed up a simple Python program using multiprocessing's Pool. Specifically: the imap_unordered function.

In my case I'm searching for a specific object with specific properties, and checking this property takes a long time, hence the reason I want to spread the load over my CPU cores.

I created the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool 
pool = ThreadPool(4) 

some_iterator = (create_item() for _ in range(100000))

results = pool.imap_unordered(my_function, some_iterator)

for result in results:
  if is_favourable(result):
    break
```

Unfortunately, after calling break, there is still a lot of activity in the threads (as can be observed in my computers activity monitor). How should I keep searching for results till I find a favourable one, or how can I stop iterating over all items using the imap_unordered iterator?

Comment: Why do you `import Pool as ThreadPool`? It's misleading at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, your example code is **not** using a `multiprocessing` `ThreadPool` because your `import` statement is wrong (it's just allowing access to the regular `Pool` class via that name).

Regardless, you can just use the `Pool`/`ThreadPool` as a context manager since Python 3.3 and put the loop inside it. This will cause its [`terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate) method to be called automatically when the context is exited (due to the `break` statement in the example below), and it will will immediately stop the working processes.

```
from multiprocessing import current_process
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from random import randint
import time

def create_item():
    return randint(0, 20)

def is_favourable(value):
    return value < 20

def my_function(value):
    print(current_process().name, value)
    time.sleep(2)
    return value * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPool(4) as pool:  # Use as context manager (Python 3.3+)
        some_iterator = (create_item() for _ in range(10000))
        start = time.time()
        results = pool.imap_unordered(my_function, some_iterator)
        for result in results:
            print('result:', result)
            if is_favourable(result):
                break  # Stop loop and exit Pool context.

    print('done')
    print(time.time() - start)
```

If you're using an older version of Python, you can just explicitly call `pool.terminate()` immediately before the `break` statement (and not use a `with` statement).

Comment: `multithreading.pool.ThreadPool` is undocumented.  I don't think your edit of the OP's question is correct.  The OP was using the documented `Pool` but renaming it `ThreadPool`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: You may be right, so I rolled my edits back.

Answer (score 3):

`Pool.terminate()` will immediately stop the working processes, while `Pool.close()` will stop submitting tasks and the processes will close once their current task is done.

`Pool.terminate()` will also be called if the `Pool` instance is garbage-collected, or by using it with `with`, so the following is a solution:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def my_function(item):
    print(mp.current_process().name,item)
    time.sleep(2) # imitate a long process
    return item * 2

def is_favourable(item):
    return item == 20   # something to look for (result of item 10)

def find():
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        some_iterator = range(100)
        results = pool.imap_unordered(my_function, some_iterator)
        for result in results:
            print(result)
            if is_favourable(result):
                return result  # pool will be terminated exiting with.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    find()
    print(time.time() - start)
```

A single thread would find item 10 in 22 seconds.  On my 8-core system it finds it in ~4 seconds:

```
SpawnPoolWorker-2 0
SpawnPoolWorker-3 1
SpawnPoolWorker-1 2
SpawnPoolWorker-5 3
SpawnPoolWorker-4 4
SpawnPoolWorker-8 5
SpawnPoolWorker-7 6
SpawnPoolWorker-6 7
SpawnPoolWorker-1 8
SpawnPoolWorker-3 9
SpawnPoolWorker-2 10
4
2
0
8
SpawnPoolWorker-4 11
SpawnPoolWorker-8 12
10
SpawnPoolWorker-5 13
6
12
SpawnPoolWorker-7 14
SpawnPoolWorker-6 15
14
SpawnPoolWorker-3 16
18
SpawnPoolWorker-1 17
SpawnPoolWorker-2 18
16
20
4.203129768371582
```